# fabric js canvas init error

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I created my first js app with canvas and it doesn't work. Code was coppied from http://fabricjs.com/ and just wrapped in jQuery.

fab.js

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      angle: 45
    });

    canvas.add(rect);
});
```

html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fabric.js</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fab.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="c">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Uncaught Error: Could not initialize `canvas` element

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to the resolution:
just replace `div` attribute with `canvas`!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fabric.js</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
        <script src="fab.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c">

        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it's working now.